# Autohotkey: Erratic Capslock after startup

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, startup

I have a simple script binding Control to Capslock:

```
Capslock::Ctrl
```

This works if I run it in session, but if I add the file into my Startup folder so that it executes with Windows start I get a very erratic behaviour where my letters are getting randomly capitalized like "THiS Is whAT HaPpENS".

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: When and how does it stop and how long does it last? Did you run it in safe mode?

Comment: When I log in to the windows machine, the script automatically activates causing this behavior. It stays like this until the end of session (or until I disable the script). I run other .ahk scripts at startup (e.g. my hotstrings and a few other bindings) - all work OK. I've tested it on 2 different machines (both Win7 64bit) with the same exact behaviour... If I disable it and then re-execute it, the behaviour is  correct (i.e. no random capitalization, sends Ctrl on keypress.)

Comment: Could other scripts cause problems? I.e., did you try running this script alone?

Comment: I  s ometimes  encounter the same problem - but I don't have any Capslock hotkey/remappings  in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happen to be remapping capslock as well, but I have no problems. I think other script might be the issue.

You can try different things.

First disable all other autohotkey scripts and any scripts that command the keyboard.

Use the prefix `$` when you specify the hotkey: `$CapsLock::Ctrl`

Call `SetCapsLockState, Off` , when the script starts.

Check the script [history](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyHistory.htm), to determine if *it* is sending the commands.

Comment: Thank you. There was no issue with the other scripts. including the two changes you've suggested solved the issue. Thank you!